# Delete matching with already matched user in all ways in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete, matching

I need to delete matching of my user which are already match. So I have a table : "MatchingUser" that look like this :

```
id | idUser1 | idUser2
1       1         2
2       1         3
3       1         2
4       2         1
```

In this example I would like to delete entry 3 and 4 because the matching is the same as the entry 1 like : if 1 match with 2 I need to delete 3 because it's the same matching and also 4 because 2 matching 1 is the same as 1 matching 2.

I already have this :

```
DELETE FROM "WU_MatchingUsers" WHERE "id" IN (SELECT "id" FROM (SELECT "id", ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY "IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2" ORDER BY "id" DESC) AS row_num FROM "WU_MatchingUsers") t WHERE t.row_num >1);
```

This one already delete same matching so in our example this one already delete the entry 3 but not the 4, I would like to add something to this query to also delete the entry 4.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: You should create a unique constraint after cleaning up the table to avoid unwanted combinations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an EXISTS condition

```
delete from MatchingUser mu1
where exists (select * 
              from MatchingUser mu2
              where mu2.id < mu1.id
                and least(mu2.iduser1, mu2.iduser2) = least(mu1.iduser1, mu1.iduser2)
                and greatest(mu2.iduser1, mu2.iduser2) = greatest(mu1.iduser1, mu1.iduser2))
```

This deletes all rows where the combination of iduser1/iduser2 is the same but have a higher ID value than the existing ones. So in this case rows with ID = 3 and ID = 4.

Comment: In this query you said "this deletes all rows where the combination of iduser1/iduser2 but this is also working in the way iduser2/iduser1 ?

Comment: The order of the values is "normalized" by using the `least()` and `greatest()` functions.